# Unable to confirm registry key was added manually

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

Dealing with [Information about power management setting on a network adapter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2740020/information-about-power-management-setting-on-a-network-adapter), I created a loop that adds a key to disable windows from cutting power to NIC cards.

```
for($i=0; $i -le 20; $i++)
{
    New-Item -Path ("REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\" + "{0:0000}" -f $i) -Name "PnPCapabilities" -Value "24"
}
```

Initially it returns

> Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0000
>
> Name                           Property
>   ----                           --------
>   PnPCapabilities                (default) : 24

So it appears to work, but when I enter regedit, I can not see the key.

Running: `Get-Itemproperty -path 'REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0001\'`

Also returns without the key I added. Though, running the loop again it returns with:

> New-Item : A key in this path already exists.
>   At line:3 char:5
>   +     New-Item -Path ("REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentContr ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (Microsoft.Power...RegistryWrapper:RegistryWrapper) [New-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

So I'm not exactly sure why I cant see the key I created. I'm on Windows 10 pro, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `"{0:0000}" -f $i)` should be `("{0:0000}" -f $i)`. You're missing the opening bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you missed an opening bracket in your code.
Besides that, I think you should use `Set-ItemProperty` instead of `New-Item` to create or change the value of an existing property.
Also, the property you are setting is of type **DWord** where in your code you surround it by quotes, making it a string.

Below code should do what you want.

```
for($i = 0; $i -le 20; $i++) {
    # you need to double-up the opening and closing curly brackets on the GUID here, otherwise
    # the '-f' formatting operator will error out trying to find the '{0:0000}' to replace..
    $path = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}}\{0:0000}' -f $i
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'PnPCapabilities' -Value 24 -Type 'DWord'    
}
```

Comment: Why do you use double curly braces `{{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}}`?

Comment: @BenderBending Because (as I've tried to explain in the code comments), if you don't **escape** these by doubling them when using the `-f` format operator, the brackets around the GUID part are not taken literally. Try and leave them out, you'll get an error. For documentation, see [String interpolation - Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters)